# Read After Write(RAW) HAZARD

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

I am confused in finding RAW dependencies whether we have to find only in adjacent instructions or non-adjacent also.

consider the following assembly code

```
I1: ADD R1 , R2, R2;

I2: ADD R3, R2, R1;

I3: SUB R4, R1 , R5;

I4: ADD R3, R3, R4;
```

FIND THE NUMBER OF READ AFTER WRITE(RAW) DEPENDENCIES IN THE Above Code.
assume ADD x,y,z =   x <- y + z

I am getting 2 dependency I2-I1 and I4-I3.

Comment: Could you specify which are the operands and which is the destination?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your homework but to my understanding of pipelining you must consider more than just the adjacent instruction, and thus l2 depends on l1, l3 depends on l1, and l4 depends on l3 and l2.

Comment: No need to shout, ok?  And this is your homework - you will not learn anything by asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that after an instruction enters the pipeline, it will take it `x` stages after which any register write by that instruction will be visible to any following instruction.

Then you have to take care of the RAW dependencies among every set of `x` consecutive instructions. In the worst case you can take `x` to be the max no. of stages in the pipeline.

Now, the case in the question looks like a HW problem and since the pipeline structure is not defined so you will have to look at the RAW dependencies over all the instructions, which in this case are:

1. I2 and I1 over R1
2. I3 and I1 over R1
3. I4 and I2 over R3
4. I4 and I3 over R4